# Issues running rmagic in IPython - Yosemite

Tags: r, ipython, osx-yosemite

I'm currently having issues trying to load rmagic into IPython since I upgraded to OSX Yosemite.
I'm using the following command:

> %load_ext rmagic

Below is the error I'm getting, and I'm not sure if it's because I upgraded to Yosemite or because I'm trying to load R incorrectly. I've pasted all the Traceback in case that's useful, but the error ends in

> ImportError: cannot import name conversion

My R version is 3.1.1
My Python version is 2.7.6
My IPython version is 2.3.0
Not sure what version rpy2 is, but I only downloaded it a few days ago so I assume it's the latest.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-691c6d73b073> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'load_ext rpy2.ipython')

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2203         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2204         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2205         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2206 
   2207     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2124                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2125             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2126                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2127             return result
   2128 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.pyc in load_ext(self, module_str)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.pyc in load_ext(self, module_str)
     61         if not module_str:
     62             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
---> 63         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
     64 
     65         if res == 'already loaded':

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.pyc in load_extension(self, module_str)
     96             if module_str not in sys.modules:
     97                 with prepended_to_syspath(self.ipython_extension_dir):
---> 98                     __import__(module_str)
     99             mod = sys.modules[module_str]
    100             if self._call_load_ipython_extension(mod):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .rmagic import load_ipython_extension

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in <module>()
     51 
     52 import rpy2.rinterface as ri
---> 53 import rpy2.robjects as ro
     54 import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpacks
     55 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py in <module>()
     16 import rpy2.rlike.container as rlc
     17 
---> 18 from rpy2.robjects.robject import RObjectMixin, RObject
     19 from rpy2.robjects.vectors import *
     20 from rpy2.robjects.functions import Function, SignatureTranslatedFunction

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py in <module>()
      5 rpy2.rinterface.initr()
      6 
----> 7 from . import conversion
      8 
      9 class RObjectMixin(object):

ImportError: cannot import name conversion
```

Comment: If you downloaded rpy2 before upgrading to Yosemite, you might try removing it and reinstalling. Also check the file listing in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects`. You can also try importing the problematic module directly: `import rpy2.robjects.conversion`.

Answer (score 1):

Minrk had it right - uninstalling and reinstalling rpy2 fixed my problem. Not sure why I didn't think of that before! Thanks.